# How to solve error : null in volley library?

Tags: android, httprequest, android-recyclerview, android-volley

In my project, I am using the volley library to get data(text and image) from the server and show the data in RecyclerView. The problem is all the requests (POST) I am sending give no response and error: null(error.getMessage() is null). I have searched about it for two days but was unable to find any solution.

This is my volley singleton class :

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class HttpController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = HttpController.class
        .getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static HttpController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized HttpController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}

}
```

I am using this code to send request :

```
StringRequest data = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                "http://odishasamaya.com/news/api/get_category_posts/", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "News request Response : " + response);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok"))
                        adapter.setNewsList(getNewsData(jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts"), progressBar, news));

                    else
                        Log.e("tabs name", "array is null");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Request Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

                params.put("id", id.get(getArguments().getInt("position")));
                Log.d("params are :", "" + params);

                return params;

            }
        };
        //HttpController.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(tag_json_req);
        HttpController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(data, tag_json_req);
```

I am unable to find what is the problem. Please help me with this or if there is any other library that I can use for HTTP requests please let me know. I need to finish this as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u add HttpController as application name inside <application> tag in manifest file?

Comment: I don't know about that. Can you please post in answer?

Comment: in your manifest file does application tag contain this <application
        android:name="HttpController" > ?

Comment: Yes I have did that.

Answer (score 1):

try to add getHeaders() method with request and check,,,, its just a hit and trial...

> it may be the issue that on request the server wouldn't find the
>   request content-type

..
try

```
pulic void doRequest(){
StringRequest data = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        "http://odishasamaya.com/news/api/get_category_posts/", new      Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "News request Response : " + response);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            if (jsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok"))
                adapter.setNewsList(getNewsData(jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts"), progressBar, news));

            else
                Log.e("tabs name", "array is null");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Request Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if(error.getMessage()==null)
        doRequest();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("id", id.get(getArguments().getInt("position")));
        Log.d("params are :", "" + params);

        return params;

    }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
};
//HttpController.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(tag_json_req);
HttpController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(data, tag_json_req);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, and after some trial and error, just before calling the queue I disallow the cache, adding the following line:

**data.setShouldCache(false);**

HttpController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(data, tag_json_req);

So the queue starts with an empty/not working cache. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a work around for this problem. I am posting it here if someone else need it in future.

```
pulic void doRequest(){
StringRequest data = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            "http://odishasamaya.com/news/api/get_category_posts/", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "News request Response : " + response);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("ok"))
                    adapter.setNewsList(getNewsData(jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts"), progressBar, news));

                else
                    Log.e("tabs name", "array is null");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Request Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(error.getMessage()==null)
            doRequest();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

            params.put("id", id.get(getArguments().getInt("position")));
            Log.d("params are :", "" + params);

            return params;

        }
    };
    //HttpController.getInstance().cancelPendingRequests(tag_json_req);
    HttpController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(data, tag_json_req);
    }
```

In the above code I have created a method to add request and in error response I am checking if error = null then again add request.

I know this is not the right way to do this but using this code application is not crashing but take some time to request again and again until request is not success.

So if someone found any better solution please post it here.
Thanks :)